# Showing Previously Saved Cards with Stripe

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

With Stripe, I want to have it so that after a User comes to my website and buys an item then next time they are able to choose (in some way) their previously used payment method. Is this possible with elements.js? During the first purchase I (naturally) have to get the payment details and I save that to a stripe customer (per https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards). Once I do that, is it possible for the customer to get an indication next time that they already have a payment option saved? What do I pass in for that (I assume something that will allow stripe to know which customer I am talking about). In short:

1) User signs up, I then create a Stripe Customer for that User and save the association between User and Customer. User then buys something, so I update the customer to have a default source.

2) I want so that next time the user will not have to enter credit card details in (1) again ^^^.

Is there a way to do this with elements.js??

Answer (score 1):

There isn't explicitly a way to do this with elements, but you can do this by [retrieving the Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/retrieve) and then iterating over the [Customer's `sources` property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-sources) and displaying those to them - or alternatively just [expand the `default_source`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) and if present, display that.

If you want to also provide a way to add a new card, you can definitely use Elements to do that along with the existing cards - this example should help get you started there: https://jsfiddle.net/ywain/k288pxqa/